# External Jquery Pass value to php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a external js file where the value is set like this.

```
setAverageResult: function(p, g) {
    var v = $e.find('.wpProQuiz_resultValue:eq(' + (g ? 0 : 1) + ') > * ');  
    v.eq(1).text(p + '%');
    v.eq(0).css('width', (240 * p / 100) + 'px');
    v.eq(2).html('<div data-score='+ p +' data-role=""></div>');         
},
```

And in php file here the value gets displayed.

```
<td class="wpProQuiz_resultValue">
    <div style="background-color: #F79646;">&nbsp;</div>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <div class="match_recd"></div>
</td>
```

What I want is instead of passing via html or text I need the variable in php file. SO as I can use the variable in php file to match the cuurent with the list.

For eg:- In js file i get value = 50

SO instead of getting div with value **50**, I need to get the variable "**p**"
AM not much aware about jquery, so please if anyone can help me out.
and then check like **if p==50 {}else{}**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the variable p, inside the data-score attribute you can do the following:

Supossing you add an id to the div, `<div id="opts" data-score='+ p +' data-role=""></div>`

get value from div

```
value = $('#opts').data('data-score');
```

or

```
value = $('#opts').attr('data-score');
```

put value to div

```
$('#opts').data('data-score', '50');
$('#opts').attr('data-score', '50');
```